# Simple OLS $\beta_1$ Formula?

Tags: statistics, regression

Reviewing my econometrics books and was just confused by the following derivation:

We use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)\left(y_{i}-\bar{y}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right) y_{i}$ to write the OLS slope estimator equation as
$$
\hat{\beta}_{1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right) y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}}
$$

I don't believe I've ever seen the above formula written that way. I don't understand how that fact above is the case, or how the formula is the same as the general $\hat\beta$ below?
$$
\hat{\beta}_{1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)\left(y_{i}-\bar{y}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}}
$$

Comment: Multiply it out and note that $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) \bar y = \bar y \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x) = \bar y (0) = 0$

Comment: sorry, multiply what out?

Comment: Your second expression $(x_i - \bar x)(y_i - \bar y) = (x_i - \bar x)y_i - (x_i - \bar x)\bar y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})( y_i - \bar{y} ) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x} ) y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x} ) \bar{y} = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x} ) y_i - \bar{y} ( n\bar{x} - n \bar{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x} ) y_i
$$